# GUI for newsbeuter?

Tags: gui, sqlite, rss-aggregator

Is there a GUI for the feed reader [newsbeuter](http://www.newsbeuter.org/)?

Or would there be an easy way to create one for it?

Or is there any other graphical feed reader that could use the `cache.db` database (SQLite) of newsbeuter?

Comment: Hurrm, wait... Was under the impression that newsbeuter's TUI is its main selling point, kind of... Why do you need a GUI when a nearly perfect TUI is available? (No, I don't use `mutt` or `pine` :) )

Comment: @DeerHunter: There are several reasons: a) It's no fun to read longer texts on the console. b) I have several hundred feeds and it's way easier to scan them in a graphical interface (in newsbeuter, I literally have to *read*). c) I want to view images inline. d) the newsbeuter TUI is slow (yeah, sounds weird, but I noticed a short loading time when opening a feed/entry, which gets pretty annoying when I browse through a few hundred posts).

Comment: unor, the only non-cloud-based solution I have for you is switching to another reader - Liferea, for instance; if you want to import existing newsbeuter database into the reader you'll have to write an ETL script (starting with `sqlite3`'s `.dump` command). Another idea to cut through the 100's of feeds is using [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com) to filter relevant items. The upshot is that you can switch between various ways of presenting the same mega-feed after putting the "badge" onto your web site. YMMV. And yes, I feel your pain on information overload...

Comment: @DeerHunter: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried Liferea some time ago, but it couldn't handle the amount of my feeds/entries (it often became unresponsive). At the moment I use RSSOwl, but it has it problems with such a big database, too. Regarding Yahoo! Pipes: I like that service, but I want to archive all entries and filter them locally.

Comment: Your solution with an archive that large has to be built around a high-performance database back-end (most feed readers as you know use substandard, high-complexity algorithms).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no GUI for newsbeuter. It does, however, have an export option to print subscriptions to either `stdout` or a file; see `man newsbeuter`:

> -e
>            Export feeds as OPML to stdout

You could simply export your subscription list as `.opml` and import the list into a graphical client of your choosing.

Comment: I'm interested in all feed entries (which are saved in `.newsbeuter/cache.db`), not just in the feed URLs (which are listed in `.newsbeuter/urls`).

Comment: Start coding... ;)

Answer (score 0):

unor, if it's been some time since you looked at Liferea, maybe take another look.  I'm using version 1.18.12 on Fedora with about 400 feeds with no real issues. I found earlier releases to be buggy and very slow to update.  Update speed still doesn't match something like NetNewsWire on OS X, but it's tolerably quick.